# C++ curve fiting to find the coefficients of a cubic?

Tags: python, c++

I have a group of data points that I need to fit a curve to and extract the coefficients of the polynomial and use them to determine the roots of the polynomial. I have a python library, [SCIPY Optimize Curve Fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) that is able to extract the coefficients, but I need to have a C++ version. I noticed the python library is based on minpack so I downloaded minpack but haven't been able to figure out how to use it. I also looked at the John Burkhardt version found [here](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/minpack/minpack.html), this is a pretty compact version of minpack but again I haven't figured out how to use it.

The python library leads me to believe the polynomial is of the form AX^2 + BX + C + D/X. 
I thought maybe I could port the SCIPY minpack to c++ but after looking at it I realized this was a bad idea, that and my python skills aren't good enough. Does anyone have any related code examples for using the C++ version of minpack, links to read, anything?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [Minuit](http://seal.web.cern.ch/seal/snapshot/work-packages/mathlibs/minuit/)!

They offer a standalone version, and it's also packaged in [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/) (a much larger data analysis framework).

I've only ever used it through ROOT's interface.